# Mac PhotoBooth dent effect in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, core-image

I'm trying to implement various distortion effects on UIImage. I found [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)
framework which work like charm for Swirl, Bulge, Pinch, Stretch, Sphere, GlassSphere etc. But now I want to apply dent effect which we can see it in macbook Photo booth application. How we can achieve such effect any idea ?

Comment: Have a look at Core Image.

Comment: Hi @TBlue, I'm not sure whether with core images we can handle dent effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Photo Booth dent effect is merely a bulge distortion with a negative scale. Photo Booth:

[image: Photo Booth dent filter]

GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter with a negative scale:

[image: Bulge distortion]

I'm surprised that you wouldn't have seen this when trying out the various filters.

Comment: Hi Brad, Thanks for your reply. I have tried GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter. But how can we apply GPUImageBulgeDistortionFilter with negative scale. Can you jus help me in it?

Comment: @Hrishikesh - `filter.scale = -1.0`

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial on using CIFilters in iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22167/beginning-core-image-in-ios-6)

[CIFilter class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[List of the CIFilters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) - I'd have a good look into the CICategoryDistortionEffect if I were you, just play around with them :)

Comment: He is not interested in Core Image.

Comment: Well he said, he's not sure whether Core Image can handle a dent effect. I posted the links to the respective Core Image filters he could use to get that effect.

Comment: Hi I think CICategoryDistortionEffect really help me in it. I'll try and guys I haven't say NO to core images. I say I have no idea core images with dent effect.

Comment: Properties of CICategoryDistortionEffect are     CIBumpDistortion,
    CIBumpDistortionLinear,
    CICircleSplashDistortion,
    CIHoleDistortion,
    CILightTunnel,
    CIPinchDistortion,
    CITwirlDistortion,
    CIVortexDistortion

Comment: It doesn't contain dent effect. So I'll try to do something with other effect.

Comment: Have you tried all of them? I'm pretty sure the Filter they use in Photo Booth is one of the CIFilters on Mac OS. But it's definitely not called CIDentSomething ;)
Also remember you can concatenate Filters to achieve a desired effect.